# delete operator - behave's strange

Tags: javascript, object

Could anyone explain what is own **non-configurable property** and **non-strict mode**?

Don't know the scenario it confuses me a lot. In my knowledge the `delete` operator removes a given property from an object. On successful deletion, it will return `true`, else `false` will be returned.

In the below example

```
var Employee = {
  age: 28,
  name: 'abc',
  designation: 'developer'
}

console.log(delete Employee.name)   // returns true
console.log(delete Employee.age)    // returns true
console.log(delete Employee.salary) // returns true
```

The employee object has both the properties `name` and `age`. but didn't contain the property `salary`. If when trying to delete a unknown property salary all of them included me assume it is returned `false` or may be undefined
but they returned also `true` if the property does not exist in the object but it returns `true`. How??? I couldn't understand this behavior.

Comment: Are you asking what the spec is, or why it is that way, or what a non-configurable property is, or what non-strict mode is, or what exactly? Anyway, why do you care if it returns true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) returns.

> true for all cases except when the property is an own non-configurable property, in which case, false is returned in non-strict mode.

That's just the way it works. "**Non-configurable property**" is the key phrase.

To expand on what epascarello states, MDN explicitly states:

> If the property which you are trying to delete does not exist, delete will not have any effect and will return `true`.

MDN also has a [whole bunch about strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Documentation is your friend (at least in this case).

Comment: could you little explain what is own non-configurable property and non-strict mode.?

Comment: But then it does return true in the case mentioned in the question? If the only case when false would be returned is that the property is non-configurable

Comment: @SudharsanS From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): *"Non-configurable properties cannot be removed. This includes properties of built-in objects like Math, Array, Object and properties that are created as non-configurable with methods like Object.defineProperty()."*

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, delete will only return `false` for non-configurable properties. An example of such a property would, for the data you mentioned in your question, be Employee.name.length, on which `delete` would be `false`.

Non-configurable properties can be created, if you're interested you can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property

From the above link, you can see how you can setup properties to be configurable (or not):

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  get: function() { return bValue; },
  set: function(newValue) { bValue = newValue; },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Comment: *`delete` will only return false for non-configurable properties* This is not entirely correct; it will also return false when applied to local variables in a function, for example, or a property on `window` IIRC.